# How to retrieve informations about an item clicked in a FragmentList

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I would like to start a profile activity when the user clicks on an item of a listFragment.
The list shows different informations about users such as: name, id, ranking...

What I'm looking for is a way to get access to the informations about the item clicked and pass the id of the user selected in the list to an intent.

An AsyncTask retrieves infos from the server and calls the adapter in order to show the details of the user in the list item. If I use in the onListItemClick:

```
    Object o=(Object)getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
    Log.e("LikeAttend Report", "Clicked list item: " + position + " Content: " + o.toString());
```

the log returns:

> Clicked list item: 1 Content: {score=7540, id=4, name= Gepp}

How can I get the id value within the method to add an Extra to the intent and start the profile activity?

I haven't found anything useful in the reference http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

**Code:**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public static class LikeFragmentList extends ListFragment 
    {
        private ListView listLike;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View likeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.likelist, container, false);
            ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) likeView.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner_like);
            String tabSocial="like";
            listLike = (ListView) likeView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            /*
             *  The asyncTask retrieves infos about the user list
             */
            new AsyncLoadSocial(getActivity(), progress, listLike).execute(uid,tabSocial);
            return likeView;

        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            super.onListItemClick (listView, view, position, id);
            // I've tried with object and cursor
            Object o = (Object) getListView().getItem(position);
            //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position); NullPointerException
            Log.e("LikeAttend Report", "Clicked list item: " + position + " Content: " +o.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Profile.class);
            //intent.putExtra("id", o.toString(0)); NullPointerException
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

***First Solution proposed***
from Emmanuel.

In the ListFragmentList:

> 

```
@Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                super.onListItemClick (listView, view, position, id);
                String infos = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                String[] info = infos.split("=");
                Log.e("LikeAttend Report", "Clicked list item: " + position + " Content: total -> " + infos + " \n Info[2] is:" + info[2]);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Profile.class);
                //intent.putExtra("id", o.toString(0));
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
```

The log returns:

> Clicked list item: 2 Content: total -> {score=0, id=12, photo=,
>   name=Beatrice Fratocchi} Info[2] is:  **12, photo**

in which the desired info is 12.

*** Second Solution proposed ***

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        super.onListItemClick (listView, view, position, id);

        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.e("LikeAttend Report", "Clicked list item: " + position +" Content: \n" + map.get(TAG_ID).toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", map.get(TAG_ID));
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just cast the resulting object from `getItemAtPosition()` to whatever you're populating the adapter with. From the looks of it, that is a `HashMap<String, String>`. Hence, try the following:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
```

After which you can retrieve the individual values with the same keys you're using to populate the map:

```
String id = map.put(TAG_ID,id);
String score = map.put(TAG_SCORE, score);
String name = map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
String photo = map.put(TAG_PHOTO, photo);
```

Just a thought: it may make more sense to create a simple POJO as a data object, rather than a map. That way you avoid having to store everything as a string.

Comment: Ok I've tried with `HashMap<String,String>` and it works, but I get an advise from eclipse: _Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to HashMap<String,String>_. It recommends me to add a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the onListItemClick() method.

Comment: You can avoid this if you use a HashMap<String,String> as your variable instead of an Object.

Comment: @narutov6: Yes, that warning is to be expected. Because of type erasure at runtime, there is nothing that prevents you from making the code break by supplying a `HashMap` with different key/value types. Hence, Java generics cannot save you here, and that's what Eclipse is warning you about. However, that is nothing to worry about in this scenario, so feel free to suppress the warning. Alternatively, a more OO approach is to set up a `User` object to represent the data that is currently in your map (as suggested earlier). That will get rid of the warning too.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `o.toString()` in a `String` variable (let's call it string). Then you can do `string.split("=")` and store this in a `String[]` (let's call it stringArray). The value corresponding to the id property will be stored at `stringArray[1]`.

Comment: As written in the Edit section, the id is an identification code received from the database. The spit method could be a good work around, thank you! I'll try to implement it and see the results. Is there any method from the Object class in order to get direct access to the desired value? Something like object.getTag("id")
Is it possible to get the desired result with the Cursor class?

Comment: I do not think it is possible using just Object. If you are using a an Adapter that extends from CursorAdapter you can use the getCursor() to get a reference of the Cursor. Then you can retrieve the information using the methods on the Cursor

Comment: Please see the _First solution proposed section_
How can I get only the value of the id?

Comment: Ok I can imagine the way to get the value of the id from a String but in my opinion it could become too much computationally expensive for this action.

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your AsyncTask somewhere you create an adapter, add the items to it and set it in the listview. There's a method in the ListView class called getAdapter() that returns a ListAdapter. Try getting an instance of that adapter in your onListItemClick and and call getItem(position) and it will return the user object of this list view item (that's assuming your adapter implementation uses your UserInfo class to fill in the list item view in the getView method)

Comment: How should I declare it? As an object? 
`Object infos = (Object) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);`

Comment: Can you show me your adapter class? If your model class is UserInfo and you use an adapter that extends ArrayAdapter<UserInfo>, then in that case all you have to do is UserInfo info = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);